# create lightuserdata in lua for luaglut glReadPixels

Tags: lua, lua-userdata, luaglut

I'm using luaglut and when I try to use the `glReadPixels` to capture a frame, I cannot prepare the last input argument for it successfully.

This is how I call the function:

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, 250, 250, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img)
```

The `img` is where I want to store the frame, but no matter in which type I define img, there's always error. The compiler always wants **lightuserdata**, but I've searching for several days and seems there is no way to create this type of data within lua.

How should I deal with this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you need a luaglut memarray or something here?

Comment: [`lua_pushlightuserdata`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_pushlightuserdata) though it would probably be more useful to create a full userdata, which can have metatables and garbage collection.

Comment: @EtanReisner Hi, maybe it should be exactly what I need. So I looked into memarray.c, it is defined as 
"typedef struct memarray {
   size_t   size;
   size_t   length;
   unsigned int flags;
   void     *data;
} memarray_t;"

So I did the following:
local img = memarray('uchar', 250 * 250 * 3);
glReadPixels(0, 0, 250, 250, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data);

But now I get the error:
bad argument #7 to 'glReadPixels' (lightuserdata expected, got nil)

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Hi, thanks for the reply, but lua_pushlightuserdata is on the C side right? I tried creating a function in C which push a lightuserdata as a return value, then I call this function in lua. But when I print out the type of the return value, it shows it's userdata again ... Do you know how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: lightuserdata and userdata both report "userdata" when run through `tostring`. The distinction is meaningless to the lua side of things so it doesn't show it to you.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Hi, I'm really new to lua and only now I see what you mean... although I get lightuserdata in lua, I can do nothing with it... can you give me any suggestions on how should I implement this full userdata for my purpose? I have no clue... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1st Update:
So I managed to get `lightuserdata` into lua, but now I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` problem. Below is how my code looks right now:

```
//"cpp_test.cpp"

extern "C" {
    #include <lua5.1/lua.h>
    #include <lua5.1/lualib.h>
    #include <lua5.1/lauxlib.h>
}

int getLightUserData_func_cpp(lua_State* L){
    int nargc = lua_gettop(L);
    if (0 != nargc){
        luaL_error(L, "Wrong number of arguments.");
        return 0;
    }
    static char var_name = 'a';
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L, (void*)&var_name);
    return 1;
}

static const struct luaL_reg lib_cpp[] = {
    {"getLightUserData_func_lua", getLightUserData_func_cpp},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

extern "C"
int luaopen_test(lua_State *L){
    luaL_register(L, "lib_lua", lib_cpp);
    return 1;
}
```

Makefile:

```
g++ -o test.so ./cpp_test.cpp  -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -llua5.1 -shared -fpic
```

Then when I use `test.so` in lua:

```
require "luagl"
require "luaglut"
require "memarray"

require "test"

print(lib_lua)
a = lib_lua.getLightUserData_func_lua()
glReadPixels(0, 0, 250, 250, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, a)
print(type(a))
print(a)
```

This is the output I get:

```
{
  getLightUserData_func_lua : function: 0x41ecbf10
}
userdata    
userdata: 0x7fe73297f050
```

So it seems to work. But when I `require("test")` in my other code, like (I only put the relevant part here):

```
-- "main.lua"
require "luagl"
require "luaglut"
require "memarray"

require "test"

HEIGHT = 250
WIDTH = 250

function captureFrame()
    color = lib_lua.getLightUserData_func_lua()
    glReadPixels(0, 0, HEIGHT, WIDTH, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, color)
end

-- main loop
glutInit(arg)
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB + GLUT_DOUBLE + GLUT_DEPTH)
if arg then title = arg[0] else title = "glut" end
glutInitWindowPosition(710, 0)
glutInitWindowSize(HEIGHT, WIDTH)
window = glutCreateWindow(title)
glutDisplayFunc(display_func)
glutReshapeFunc(reshape_func)

local terminal = false
while not terminal do
    io.read()
    glutMainLoopEvent()
    captureFrame()
end
```

I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` when `captureFrame()` is called. Can anyone help me with it? Thanks a lot!

---

2nd Update:
OK, I found the bug, the only think to change is in `cpp_test.cpp`. NOTE that the old line is commented off:

```
int getLightUserData_func_cpp(lua_State* L){
    int nargc = lua_gettop(L);
    if (0 != nargc){
        luaL_error(L, "Wrong number of arguments.");
        return 0;
    }
    // static char var_name = 'a';
    static unsigned char var_name[3][255][255] = {{{0}}};
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L, (void*)&var_name);
    return 1;
}
```

This way the pointer type matches the image data that it will point to.
Thanks a lot guys for all the suggestions :D

Comment: @EtanReisner And do you think it is caused by the method I created the `lightuserdata` or anything? Or is it better to use `memarray`? I didn't manage to use `memarray` successfully with `glReadPixels`, can you tell me more specifically how to use it?