# How to use luaglut function glReadPixels() in lua?

Tags: lua, ffi, luaglut

I'm using [luaglut](https://github.com/LuaDist/luaglut) to do some graphics in lua. And I am struggling with this function `glReadPixels`, particularly with its last input argument `GLvoid *pixels`.

```
void glReadPixels (GLint x, GLint y, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, GLenum type, GLvoid *pixels);
```

`pixels` is a pointer type so in lua it is of type `lightuserdata`. I managed to get a `lightuserdata` type variable let's say `img` in lua, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619497/create-lightuserdata-in-lua-for-luaglut-glreadpixels); however, after I get the frame I wanna grab into `img` by calling:

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, 250, 250, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img)
```

I could do nothing with `img`. I tried creating a same structure in lua using ffi and coverting this `img` to a [torch.Tensor](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md) type, but it is too slow since I have to assign the values pixel by pixel.

So I am asking here if there is better ways to use this `glReadPixels` function to get `img` than this troublesome approach that I took? Both `table` and `torch.Tensor` types of `img` are OK. Thank you in advance!